# Including Covariate P-Values in Multiple Comparison Corrections"

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, multiplicity

I'm currently working on a statistical analysis involving multiple comparisons and I'm uncertain about a specific aspect of the process. Specifically, my question is about the inclusion of p-values from covariates when applying corrections for multiple comparisons.

In my model, there are several covariates that I'm adjusting for. These covariates are not the primary hypotheses of interest and are included to account for possible confounding. I will not be looking at the p values and these covariates are defined *pre-hoc*.

While I am not sure it matters, it should be noted that the analysis comes from historical survey data from 2008 to 2015 (the data gathered was not specifically aimed at examining these particular hypotheses).

I am aware that when correcting for multiple comparisons, such as using the Bonferroni or FDR methods, we typically adjust the p-values to control for the family-wise error rate or the false discovery rate. However, I'm unsure whether this adjustment should also apply to the p-values obtained from the covariates in my model.

**Is it standard practice to include the p-values of covariates in the correction process for multiple comparisons?** Or are these generally excluded from such adjustments?

Any **references** to guide best practices in this scenario would be highly appreciated. A reference would be ideal to share when there is pushback.

I have read through:
Garcia, L. F. (2015). The need for multiple corrections in the assessment of the importance of differences. Colombian Journal of Anesthesiology, 43(2), 130-135. DOI: 10.1016/j.rcae.2014.11.004.

Nakagawa, S. (2004). A farewell to Bonferroni: the problems of low statistical power and publication bias. Behavioral Ecology, 15(6), 1044-1045. DOI: 10.1093/beheco/arh107.

Benjamini, Y., & Hochberg, Y. (1995). Controlling the false discovery rate: a practical and powerful approach to multiple testing. Journal of the royal statistical society: series B (Methodological), 57(1), 289-300. DOI: 10.1111/j.2517-6161.1995.tb02031.x.

Which don't give specific context involving covariates.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicity corrections only apply when you draw *inference*, they in essence adjust the critical value of your test statistic before you declare 'significance' to maintain a joint error rate.

Since nothing will be inferred from these covariates themselves, the whole concept of multiplicity is meaningless as far as they are concerned. These are [nuisance parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_parameter), and even if you were to correct them for multiplicity this would have no impact on your actual model - the estimates and covariance will remain entirely the same, only the *P*-value associated to each specific parameter would change. It sounds like you will draw your inference from a single effect, so it's only that one that should be adjusted.

I would go as far as to say that you indeed shouldn't even look at or report those covariate *P*-values (most software packages will still give them to you by default), they would only answer a question similar to "should we have included this covariate" where you've already decided ahead of time that you will do so regardless.

Comment: It is good to know I am in the right track and it makes sense that if I am not doing inference, then I don't need to do the adjustments. I have been having some difficulty finding concrete references on this.

Comment: Well, the point is, there *is no hypothesis being tested* in these covariates. I'm not sure if there's anything out there that explicitly says you (don't) need to do adjustments for all possible hypotheses that you aren't testing.. In fact, you might even argue that unless your study is strictly confirmatory (say, a pivotal clinical trial) you shouldn't correct for multiplicity too much.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have been finding. It seems that just because a p-value is being generated by the statistical software there is this knee-jerk reaction to adjust for multiplicity in this specific field (I work as a biostatistician and have moved to survey metrics in psychology).  Even when you shouldn't be reporting those results.